# JXL API read from one excel sheet and write it to another excel sheet in java is doing for only limited Rows and Columns

Tags: java, jxl

I have already done search of any similar query being asked in this forum and didnt get any. So, iam asking this doubt.

**Objective** :-> To try Read data from one excel sheet and create new excel sheet and paste that data in it using ONLY JXL API as of now. Iam already using .xls file to read.

**Issue** :-> Iam able to do that but it is somehow, only doing it for 3 Columns and 3 Rows. If iam giving another data in additional cell, it gives 
error :-

```
"**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
at myTimesPackage.ReadNwriteJXL.main(ReadNwriteJXL.java:42)**"

[Code image][1]

    package myTimesPackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class ReadNwriteJXL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {

        File f = new File ("D:\\Rajiv\\Selenium\\4jxl.xls");
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
        Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);

        File f1 = new File ("D:\\Rajiv\\Selenium\\w1.xls");
        WritableWorkbook wb1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(f1); 
        WritableSheet ws1 = wb1.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);

        int b = s.getColumns();
        System.out.println("The No. of Columns in the Sheet are = " + b);
        int a = s.getRows();
        System.out.println("The No. of Rows in the sheet are = " +a);

        String p [][]= new String[s.getColumns()][s.getRows()];

        for (int i=0; i<b; i++){

            for (int j=0; j<a; j++){

                p[i][j]=s.getCell(j, i).getContents();

                Cell c = s.getCell(i, j);
                System.out.println(c.getContents());

                Label l = new Label(j,i,p[i][j]);
                ws1.addCell(l);

            }
        }

        wb1.write();
        wb1.close();
        System.out.println("File Written");
    }
}
```

> Input .xls file is :-> 3x3 matrix

```
raj 3   5
12  9   22
22  24  25
```

Please guide me what mistake iam doing. Thanks

Comment: Please fix your tags... this question has nothing to do with selenium and you haven't included the language or library tags.

Comment: @JeffC - Done. Thanks

Comment: Can anybody guide me what mistake iam doing. Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks